# ListView inside Gallery is possible ? But unable to swipe my listview?

Tags: android

I am take Gallery,while attach images i am take listview in xml.

ListView and images are displayed. But unable to swipe listview.

Thanks in Advance.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        Gallery gallery = null;
        Activity appContext = this;
        int[] images = { R.drawable.banana, R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.pineapple,
                R.drawable.lemon, R.drawable.mango };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

            GalleryAdapter ga = new GalleryAdapter();
            gallery.setAdapter(ga);
        }

        class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 2;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int arg0) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
                v = LayoutInflater.from(appContext).inflate(R.layout.test1, null);

                ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Here i am attch a Adapter to set images for ListView

```
ListAdapter la = new ListAdapter(appContext, images);
                    lv.setAdapter(la);

                    return v;
                }

            }
        }
```

My other getView method for ListAdapter is

```
@Override
    public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(appContext).inflate(R.layout.list_style, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_listStyle);
        iv.setImageResource(images[pos]);
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: ... that's how end putting scrollable into scrollable ...

Comment: give me any idea please

Comment: Aren't you use a scroll of listView?

Answer (score 0):

You should not put a listView in Gallery. It's not build for that, it's build to handle one static view. Most likely an image. Besides that it's deprecated sinc v16:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Other possiblities include: HorizontalScrollView or ViewPager.

Most likely you must use a ViewPager. It's packaged in the Support Library and thus available from Android 1.6.

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

To answer your question: The Gallery view intercepts all swipes (horizontal and vertical). That's why the ListView doesn't scroll. Where the ViewPager only intercepts horizontal swipes, in a ViewPager the ListView will work.

For an example look here:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 0):

Use view pager or tabview for your  purposes.They are desined to hold other views, while gallery is for single object per view.